# How to dynamically add integer values from textbox to a int array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I want to create a form with a button where button can create a set of components(2 text boxes, 1 label). I want the value entered in the text boxes to be stored into a int array.

I have worked this far
Button Click Event

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AddNewLabel();
        AddNewTextBox1();
        AddNewTextBox2();
    }
```

Adds Textboxes

```
 public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox AddNewTextBox1()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(txt1);
        txt1.Top = txtBoxCounter * 28;
        txt1.Left = 125;
        string txtName1 = "txtLL" + txtBoxCounter;
        txt1.Name = txtName1;
        string txtValue1 = txt1.Text;
        lowerLimit[txtBoxCounter-1] = Int32.Parse(txtValue1);
        return (txt1);


    }
```

Adds Labels

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Label AddNewLabel()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Label lbl = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.Controls.Add(lbl);
        lbl.Top = lblCounter * 28;
        lbl.Left = 15;
        lbl.Text = "Range" + lblCounter;
        lblCounter = lblCounter + 1;
        return (lbl);
    }
```

After Start Debbuging
[image: Inital Form]

After Button Click
[image: After Button Click]

Comment: Why not just create a user control containing a couple of text boxes and a label?

Comment: Creating your own grid control like this is a Very Bad idea.  Use DataGridView instead.  Many other ones out there.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to this: you could store `TextBox` objects that you create in a collection in an instance variable on the form, or since text boxes are already added to `this.Controls`, you could walk them dynamically.

The approach is up to you; here is an example of using the second approach:

```
var total = this.Controls
    .OfType<TextBox>
    .Sum(tb => {
        int val;
        if (int.TryParse(tb.Text, out val)) {
            return val;
        }
        return 0;
    });
```

**Note:** You need to import `System.Linq` for this approach to compile.